# Ajax/json call to asmx web service completes sucessfully but cant display resulting data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asmx

I'm sure I am not formatting the results correctly or something like that. Any help appreciated. Thanks, Gary

**This is the JavaScript portion:**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../ajaxservices.asmx/HelloWorld',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{}',
         success: function(data){

           that.resultsField.innerHTML = data.d; 

        },
        error: function() {

            that.resultsField.innerHTML = 'Error'; 
        }
    });
```

**This is the web service portion:**

```
namespace WorkbenchWebServices
{
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class ajaxservices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

        public string HelloWorld(string name)
        {

            return "Gary Hello World-";
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what "that" is.  When setting html it is set .html(data).  I think your syntax may be wrong

Comment: Put a javascript alert in your success function to see if something is coming back. `alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));`

Answer (score 0):

hAs Matt says, "that" doesn't exists...
try using:

```
$("#result").html(data);
//instead of using
//that.resultsField.innerHTML = data.d; 

<div id="result"></div>
```